# Configure WSO2 Identity Server with Active Directory?

Tags: wso2, federated-identity, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to stand up WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 with Active Directory as the primary user store.  I have connectivity, LDAPS, working database, etc. and can login to the admin console as the admin user I have chosen, and can successfully search for AD users and see roles.

However, if I try to show the details of a user, or change their password, I receive errors.  For example, when attempting to change password, I see in the logs:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-15 16:14:15,135] ERROR
{org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  User testuser does
not exisit in the user store
{org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient}
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException:
UserAdminUserAdminException
```

but I have looked up this user and clicked the "change password" link in the resulting display, so it was able to at least find that user in the search.

I suspect that the AD roles of the user that I have configured for the LDAP connection are not sufficient to perform these tasks, but am unsure.  Am I on the right trail, and if so, what are the requirements for this user?  Or, is there something else to troubleshoot related to these errors?

UPDATE 4/18/2016:
OK when I added the debug suggested in an answer (log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG), I noticed that the tool was searching for the user by CN and not finding it:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:19:42,394] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener} -  Pre update credential by admin is called in IdentityMgtEventListener {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:19:42,394] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener} -  Updating credentials of user astudent16 by admin with a non-empty password {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:19:42,394] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user astudent16 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:19:42,409] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(cn=astudent16)) in SearchBase:  {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:19:42,472] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for astudent16 is null {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:19:42,472] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: astudent16 exist: false {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:19:42,487] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  User astudent16 does not exisit in the user store {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient}
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
```

I referred back to documentation, and the vendor documentation suggests that for Active Directory, the UserNameAttribute in user-mgt.xml be set to CN - we had this set to sAMAccountName.

So, we changed to CN, and now the error is different:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:30:46,338] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user A Student16 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:30:46,354] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(cn=A Student16)) in SearchBase:  {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:30:46,354] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for A Student16 is CN=A Student16,OU=2016,OU=Students,OU=Accounts,DC=some,DC=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:30:46,354] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: A Student16 exist: true {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:30:46,463] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in A Student16 : A Student16 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-04-18 10:30:46,463] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  Can not access the directory service for user : A Student16 {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager}
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'DC=some,DC=org'
 ]; remaining name 'CN=A Student16'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3112)
```

Comment: Can you check repository/logs/wso2carbon.log and see if there are any more details about this error? Also why don't you try applying IS Service Pack 1 to your setup and check this? Many issues that were available in IS 5.0.0 was fixed in SP1.

Comment: I am using a packaged version of the IS from a vendor, so I am stuck at version 5.0.0.  Packaged version is from Ellucian higher ed ERP vendor: http://www.ellucian.com/Software/Ellucian-Identity-Service/

Comment: Are you getting the latest error when you trying to retrieve information of a user you created before you change the user-mgt.xml?

Comment: Yes, all of these users were created in AD prior to installation of this product.  And I can retrieve users via search, but then get this error when trying to change the password for them via the link for each one in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

Add following the line to `<IS_HOME>repository/conf/log4j.properties` file, and try the scenario which failed.  Also attach `wso2caron.log` file to analyze the issue.

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG
```

Also attach user-mgt.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am having the same problem you are. I was able to get the password recovery to work for a user by changing the UserSearchBase so it fully referenced the OU for the user.

In our case we have users in:

```
OU=FacStaff,OU=People,DC=SomeCollege,DC=edu
OU=Students,OU=People,DC=SomeCollege,DC=edu
OU=Sysusers,OU=PrivUsers,DC=SomeCollege,DC=edu
```

By specifying the full OU, the password recovery works for users in that OU, but users in any other OU cannot even log in.

I want to have my UserSearchBase set to DC=SomeCollege,DC=edu so it can search our whole tree, and this does work for authentication, but not anything where it has to write to Active Directory.

I can replicate the error by doing an ldapmodify with an ldif that leaves out part of the DN for a user, so I suspect the problem lies in the updateCredentialByAdmin function in that it is attempting to use the CN and UserSearchBase where it should be using the full DN.

I have also tried using multiple UserSearchBase entries, separating them with the hash character.  Again, it works for authentication, but not updates.